# compton i3 tabbed/stacked transparency background image

Tags: arch-linux, gui, i3, compton

I have a rule in compton (on i3) that when I am in tabbed/stacked mode, I see not a window from the tabbed container but my background image behind my semitransparent terminal. But for some reason, this is not working when thunar is in the tabbed container. I always see thunar behind the terminal. Why? How to fix? What do you need to give help?

snippet: `opacity-rule = [ "0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'" ];`

Works for all except thunar (I see thunar and not bg then behind my terminal). Works fully on pc (also for thunar) but works not for thunar on laptop.

Answer (score 3):

i had kind of the same problem; certain programs didnt seem to take the opacity rule. i changed the opacity-rule to:

```
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[0]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[1]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[2]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[3]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[4]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
```

which seems to have solved the problem